# Joining spring jpa and external source

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm looking for a pattern/approach to solve the following problem. I've got a table, for example:

```
create table cars
(
  id number generated by default as identity;
  user_id varchar2(100);
... 
);
```

And an entity for it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cars")
public class Car implements Serializable
{
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userId;
...
}
```

And I need to use user' name and other user's attributes as well.

The problem is, that users are stored in the external iam (keycloak in my case) and `user_id` is the id of the user in the iam. So, I've made a repository with feign for it. It's a repository by its nature but not a jpa repository though. Something like:

```
@Data
public class user
{
  String id;
  String username;
...
}
```

```
@Repository
@FeignClient(name = "users", url = "${usersclient.url}", configuration = OAuthFeignConfig.class)
public interface UserRepository
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "${usersclient.baseuri}" + "/users/{id}")
    public User findById(@PathVariable String id);
...
}
```

Now my question is: how could I join these two to have user's data in the `Car` entities?

I see following approaches:

1. To add `@Transient User` field to the `Car` and to inject `UserRepository` into `Car` entity somehow, then to set this `Car::user` in the getter/structor. But I have no idea how to inject, since `Car` is just an entity and spring creates them with `new` which means that annotations won't work
2. To make a `CarDto` with all the `Car` data plus additional `User` field in it. Then to retrieve and add `User` in the mapper. But it looks quite redundant in my case, also, there could me many different dto implementations, so I'd need to inherit them from some common dto ancestor which adds unnecessary complexity to the code.
3. To implement it in the ``CarService```, but it is like moving "join" logic to the service layer, which alsoo does not sound good for me.

My question: what is the pattern to implement such a things in sprong?

Thank you.